# Display value from checkbox in console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Well this is probably an easy question but I've been figure this one out. I would like to display the value of a checkbox in the `console.log` so I can use it to fire a AJAX call. But the values of every checkbox is the same (the first one).

I have spent some time on google and I for what I read there, I should put the checkbox in an `array`. But I can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code at the moment.

```
<!-- Custom taxonomy checkboxes -->
     <?php
        $taxonomy = 'locatie';
        $queried_term = get_query_var($taxonomy);
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, 'slug='.$queried_term);
            if ($terms) {
              foreach($terms as $term) {
                $name = $term->name;
                echo "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2'>
                    <form id='location'>
                        <input class='checkIt' type='checkbox' value='".$name."' name='location' id='".$name."_id'>&nbsp;&nbsp;".$name."
                    </form>
                </div>";                             
              }
        }
    ?>
<!-- /Custom taxonomy checkboxes -->
```

```js
$('.checkIt').change(function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.post('../wp-content/themes/mysite/includes/search-team-wp.php',{value:value}, function(data){
        $('#search_results_team').hide().fadeIn(1100);
         $("#search_results_team").html(data);
         console.log(value);
    });
});
```

});

Everything works, even the AJAX call, except the console.log output so I can't sent different values trough the AJAX call. Any help would be really nice!

Comment: So you're able to post the data and event successfully running the callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
var value = $(this).val();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you're selecting *all* `.checkIt` elements in the selector within the `change` event. When you call `val()` on a collection of elements jQuery will only return the value of the first one.

To fix this you only need to get the value of the element that raised the `change` event. To do that, use the `this` keyword within the handler:

```
var value = $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ajax call as given below,

```
var value = $(this).val(); 
     $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:'../wp-content/themes/mysite/includes/search-team.php',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                      value:value
                    },
                   success:function(data){
                     $('#search_results_team').hide().fadeIn(1100);
                     $("#search_results_team").html(data);
                    console.log(value)
                    }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The only problem is that while the Ajax event fires, the value isn't displayed in the console.log. And the `#search_results_team` doesn't respond like it did with my code?

Comment: are you performing opration on $('#search_results_team') after ajax scope? because ajax is async call so next statement will execute before ajax call complete it's operation. to get the value you can also try "var obj = $(this); and colsole.log statement will like  console.log(obj.val());

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('.checkIt').is(':checked')
```

This will give you the checked box.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery.val() for checkbox always return ... the value you defined, despite of the checked state.

If you want something like when check return value, else return undefined you should do: `value = $('.checkIt:checked').val();`